# command keeps echoing because web page tries refreshing

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, ethernet, web-server

I want to execute a action only once when I press web page button but as the page tries refreshing the action gets executed in a loop.
I am using the wifimanualwebserver example for esp8266.
Please suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it possible in your case, but you might send and ID with it which you increase every time the button has been (really) clicked (thus not refreshed). On the receiver side, check if the ID is already received, if yes, do not execute it.